# Can't save comma separated number string in varchar2()

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a list of items I want to add in a single click, for this purpose I created a table with a column with a type varchar2(4000), in this column I want to list id's that refer to the other table so I can paste the value of this column as a parameter. ex. select t.* from table_name t where t.point_id in (varchar2 string of comma seprated point_ids).

The problem I've got is that when I put more than 1 id in the varchar2 field I get ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

How can I avoid this error? My field is varchar2, not number and I don't want it to be converted. I need the value I'm parsing to be saved. ex. (11, 12)

Picture of my Table:
[image]

EDIT: Note - My select is working okay, the problem I'm having is with saving the information.

My Insert :

```
procedure lab_water_pointsgroup (v_group_id lab_water_pointsgroups.group_name%type,
                          v_group_name lab_water_pointsgroups.group_code%type,
                          v_group_code lab_water_pointsgroups.lab_points_ids%type,
                          v_lab_points_ids lab_water_pointsgroups.group_id%type) as
begin
update lab_water_pointsgroups
   set group_name = v_group_name,
       group_code = v_group_code,
       lab_points_ids = v_lab_points_ids
 where  group_id = v_group_id;
if ( SQL%RowCount = 0 ) then
insert into lab_water_pointsgroups
  (group_id, group_name, group_code, lab_points_ids)
values
  (v_group_id, v_group_name, v_group_code, v_lab_points_ids);
end if;
end;
```

Comment: That error message is probably a good thing, because it is generally _not_ good to store CSV data in a single SQL column.  Why do you want to store CSV like this?

Comment: Are you **sure** that column's datatype is VARCHAR2? Please, post table's description (run DESC table_name in SQL*Plus and copy the result over here - edit the question, don't post it as a comment).

Comment: I get invalid SQL Statement trying to run desc. Edit: Updated with picture of my table.

Comment: can you post your code for insert statement in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. Normalize your data model and you don't have that problem

Comment: @Gag I updated my question.

Comment: Run a `MERGE` statement using the result obtained from the select query in the answer  instead of update and insert

Comment: In Oracle this error could also be caused by the character string being too long for the field... Try to substr it to the length of your column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you defined parameters for your procedure:

```
v_group_id        lab_water_pointsgroups.group_name%type,
v_group_name      lab_water_pointsgroups.group_code%type,
v_group_code      lab_water_pointsgroups.lab_points_ids%type,
v_lab_points_ids  lab_water_pointsgroups.group_id%type
```

I suspect that you made mistake with types, because `id` has `name` type, `name` has `code` type etc. So it should be:

```
v_group_id        lab_water_pointsgroups.group_id%type,
v_group_name      lab_water_pointsgroups.group_name%type, 
v_group_code      lab_water_pointsgroups.group_code%type,
v_lab_points_ids  lab_water_pointsgroups.lab_points_ids%type
```

And I suggest to use `merge` instead of this `update` / `insert`, but it's not what you asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how exactly I can help you here as you gave no example. Have a look at the below demo, maybe the contruct with `xmltable` solves your problem. HTH KR

```
create table testtab (id number);
insert into  testtab values (1);

select * from testtab where id in ('1');   -- works
select * from testtab where id in (1);     -- works
select * from testtab where id in (1,2);   -- works
select * from testtab where id in ('1,2'); -- ORA-01722: invalid number
select * from testtab where id in (select to_number(xt.column_value) from xmltable('1,2') xt); -- works
```

Comment: When I add the id's manually by selecting for update I don't have any problems. But when using a procedure to update the value I get the error.

Comment: *"varchar2 string of comma seprated point_ids"* is a string. So your query is effectively `where 11 in ('11,12')`. Because you're comparing a number to a string Oracle attempts to cast `'11,12'` to a number; it clearly isn't a valid number so Oracle hurls ORA-1722. You need to convert the string into a series of numeric IDs. This is why Peter's `xmltable()` implementation will solve your problem.

Comment: My problem isn't reading the id's, it's updating the lab_point_ids value.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in that you don't make difference between variable containing comma separated numbers and actual enumeration in the 'in' operator.  After your code analize and preparation to execution your statement will be like `.. id in ('1,2,3')`  instead of `..id in (1,2,3)`, did you notice  differnce ? So you need to transform comma separated values into array or in this case into collection. Your code should be like this:

```
select t.*
  from table_name t
 where t.point_id in
       (select regexp_substr(YOUR_VARCHAR2_COLUMN_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, level)
          from dual
        connect by regexp_substr(YOUR_VARCHAR2_COLUMN_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```